# Cloning a Oracle Database Schema

Tags: oracle, docker, clone

I have an Oracle 12c Instance with a scheme 'wadmin' user, this instance has tables, view, data, triggers, sequences etc.

For quick spinning of docker images, I need to clone the db schema as fast as possible , so that I can create another user 'wadmin1' link it to new docker and start my testing.

Any CLI/tools for the same, does oracle provide any options?

Comment: Any Tools in AWS or AWS RDS will also work!

Comment: If you're using Docker, why not simply create a custom Docker image that already contains your schema? This way, as soon as you launch the container, you're ready to go - no need to copy anything.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: How reliable is Docker for DB? I read in multiple forums not to use docker for DB as its ephemeral?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if this is exacly what you are looking for but you can export your Oracle schema using ORACLE DataPump tool. This involves storing exported schema in the Oracle directory. While exporting schema to file you can transform the schema name, omit unnecessary tables or data etc. Exported files with database schema can be later used for imported to new database instance. More information regarding Oracle DataPump you can find here. https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g#SchemaExpImp.

Alternatively you can have scripts that create the database stored in the Git repository and integrate your builds with too called Flyway https://flywaydb.org/ which can be used to automatize of database schema creation. This is also really convenient from source control point of view. All changes on the schema are pull requested.

In my team we use OracleDataPump when we want to recreate the database together with the data, Flyway is used as a part of our continues integration.

Comment: I have used Oracle Data Pump, its little slow as the data is huge (Close to 10 GB), and also it involved I/O, it takes time

Comment: You can also export only metadata of your database by adding CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY while starting the expdp from the command line